# build.artifactstagingdirectory doesn't exist Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, clickonce

[image]

I'm trying to publish a ClickOnce application. To do so, I'm building the project with the msbuild `publish` target argument, copying the files to the artifact staging directory, then attempting to upload that directory via FTP.

However, the ftpupload task is failing:
[image: image2]

With the following error:

> 550 The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Can you share the logs of the Copy task and the full log of the FTP task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever reason, removing the `/` at the begging of the Remote Directory field fixed it. Most say the `/` at the beginning is needed, however. It might vary from one FTP server to another.

Comment: Great, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/), so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> 550 The system cannot find the file specified.

This error doesn't indicate that the specified files are missing in `build.artifactstagingdirectory` folder.

Actually the task would always succeed with the warning `Could not find any files to upload` even when the `build.artifactstagingdirectory` folder is empty:

[image]

To make the FTP upload task work successfully, you may need to check your `Remote directory` input of that task and make sure your FTP remote Server is configured well.

1.Assuming your remote home directory is `C:\FTPfolder`. You should use `/TestFolder/`as input if you want to upload the files to `C:\FTPfolder\TestFolder`. (Be careful about the slash)

[image]

2.If your upload task would create a new folder in remote directory during this process, you should make sure the user account has the related directory access like creating sub-folders...

PS: I run this pipeline in my self-hosted agent to upload files to remote directory in remote machine with Serv-U ftp server. The task works well in my side.

Comment: For some reason, removing the `/` at the beginning of Remote Directory makes it upload successfully

Comment: @Abِ Strange but really good news, in my case it only works perfectly with `/` at the beginning. Could you add it as self-answer in case someone may encounter similar issue?